# Cannot get the $scope.data populated from service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, scope

I can't get my scope variable populated from a object resulted from a service.

here is my service :

```js
app.factory("studentService", ['$http','$q','$localstorage','$state', 
    function($http,$q,$localstorage,$state) {

 return{
    getPersonalInfo:function(pi_id)
            {
                    return $http.get(app.baseUrlServer + app.baseUrlUser +   '/getpersonalinfo/' + pi_id)
                    .then(function(response){
                        if (response.data) {
                        
                            return response.data;
                        } else {
                            // invalid response
                            return $q.reject(response.data);
                        }
                    },function(response){
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    });
            }
   }
 
 /* my controller */
 var app_ctrl = angular.module('app.controllers');
app_ctrl.controller('MatesprofileController', 
 ['$scope','$stateParams','studentService','$localstorage',
 function($scope, $stateParams, studentService , $localstorage) {
      
      $scope.personalInfo=[];
    
    studentService.getPersonalInfo($stateParams.pi_id).then(function(data){
      
      $scope.personalInfo.push(data);
         
     }); 
  
    
    }
```

I can't get my $scope.personalInfo array populated even though I already pushed the data object into personalInfo array.

in fact, when I console.log(data) inside of the .then function, It outputs the data, but when I do the same, just outside of the .then blocks, it shows nothing..

please, help me. I'm totally stuck of this

---

### **update**

I've done the following :

```js
app.factory("studentService", ['$http', '$q', '$localstorage', '$state',
      function($http, $q, $localstorage, $state) {


        return {
          getPersonalInfo: function(pi_id) {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            $http.get(app.baseUrlServer + app.baseUrlUser + '/getpersonalinfo/' + pi_id)
              .then(function(response) {
                if (response.data) {
                  defer.resolve(response.data);
                } else {
                  // invalid response
                  defer.reject(response.data);
                }
              }, function(response) {
                // invalid response
                defer.reject("Error");
              });
            return defer.promise;

          }

        }

      }


      /* CONTROLLER */

      var app_ctrl = angular.module('app.controllers');
      app_ctrl.controller('MatesprofileController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'studentService', '$localstorage',
          function($scope, $stateParams, studentService, $localstorage) {

            //$scope.personalInfo=[];
            studentService.getPersonalInfo($stateParams.pi_id).then(function(data) {
              $scope.data = data;
              console.log($scope.data); //this shows up correctly, but it executed latest

            });

            console.log($scope.data); // this shows up first in the console, but it's empty
          }
```

Still not workgin :(

### **update**

Finally, I get it worked by simply to not using the then() function. because the service returns the actual data instead of promise, thus, on the controller only need to call it as a variable.

example:

$scope.data =  studentService.getPersonalInfo($stateParams.pi_id);

voila!, thanks for those who helped me, special thanks to my friends @arwaniali for suggesting me this solution and also all of you who have answered this questions. thanks : )

Comment: `console.log` outside of your `then` function will show nothing because it will run before your asynchronous `then` callback has a chance to fire. try doing `console.log($scope.personalInfo)` right after pushing the data. If it shows what you expect, then you are in fact populating your `$scope` object and all is well.

Comment: Are you not seeing this data out in your HTML? Can you post that?

Comment: How if I want to return data, instead of promise? Is my code wrong?

Comment: @azium : no, I can't event to print it in the console

Answer (score 1):

Your `getPersonalInfo` is inconsistent in what it returns. If the http call is successful and you get data, you return the actual data rather than a promise. If you want your function to always return a promise, then you should change `getPersonalInfo` the following way:

```
getPersonalInfo:function(pi_id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(app.baseUrlServer + app.baseUrlUser +   '/getpersonalinfo/' + pi_id)
        .then(function(response){
            if (response.data) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            } else {
               // invalid response
               deferred.reject(response.data);
            }
         },function(response){
               // invalid response
               deferred.reject("Error");
         });
    return deferred.promise; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $http service returns a promise. You should return this promise to your controller, and then test the return data and do the appropriate error handling if necessary.

```
 app.controller('MatesprofileController', ['$scope','studentService', function($scope,  studentService ) {
   $scope.personalInfo=[];
      studentService.getPersonalInfo(123).then(function(data){
        if(data !== undefined && data.length > 0)
          $scope.personalInfo = data;
        else
          console.log('handle error');


        console.log($scope.personalInfo);
      });
 }]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzNBT6pDqhqcAseWVX5I?p=preview

Comment: I disagree. The controller should be as agnostic to the data handling as possible, and only help glue the data to the view. The error handling should be done inside the service. Also, your answer doesn't solve his 'problem' because you've just moved the error handling, but he was in fact getting the data inside `then` already.

Comment: Yes you're right. The answer below should be the correct solution.

Comment: Well, looks like it's the same way I did. I tried the below solution before, and still I can't pass the data from the service to my array

Comment: It's so weird, I tried all of the above solutions and it's not working. I still can't get the $scope.personalInfo populated. Even tough I can get the data as an object, but still can't pass it to another variable :(

Comment: Assuming your endpoint is working correctly, the solution listed by @yarons should work. http://plnkr.co/edit/lXItIVXXobBocK2gWPTA?p=preview